# rvm install throws ruby installation error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby using [Installfest tutorial](https://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/osx_rvm)

When I run `rvm install ruby 2.3.8` I get the following error:

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/stella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@global GEM_PATH= /Users/stella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby -d /Users/stella/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/setup.rb --no-document'
```

How to fix this?

I tried other suggestions for similar problems on SO but nothing worked so far.

Comment: I'm not able to help here but it might be useful to include the solutions you've already tried that didn't work to help anyone who might want to help out narrow things down.

Comment: Also, add the *entire* error message or log output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below command may help for you

1. source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
2. rvm update
3. rvm reload
4. rvm install 2.3.8